# morris chart -> html to pass on a variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, morris.js

The code below generates a morris chart with daily weekly or monthly data. This is fine, however, I would need the variable from the dropdown "cars"to be passed on and create a var in php for running a sql select. 
Anyone could help me to generate this var in php?
Many many thanks!!! 
Jav

```
    <div id="line-chart" style="height: 300px;"><h3 style="text-align: center;">Waiting for you to choose the data you want to display</h3></div>
<hr/>
<button data-type="day">Day</button> | <button data-type="week">Week</button> | <button data-type="month">Month</button>
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
     </html>

<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
    $('button').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#line-chart').empty();
        var type = $(this).data('type')

        , month = [
                { y: '2012-06', a: 100, b: 90 },
                { y: '2012-07', a: 75,  b: 65 },
                { y: '2012-08', a: 50,  b: 40 },
                { y: '2012-09', a: 75,  b: 65 },
                { y: '2012-10', a: 50,  b: 40 },
                { y: '2012-11', a: 75,  b: 65 },
                { y: '2012-12', a: 100, b: 90 }
            ]

        , week = [
                { y: '2012 W1', a: 10, b: 20 },
                { y: '2012 W2', a: 50,  b: 10 },
                { y: '2012 W3', a: 40,  b: 80 },
                { y: '2012 W4', a: 90,  b: 25 },
                { y: '2012 W5', a: 10,  b: 20 },
                { y: '2012 W6', a: 35,  b: 60 },
                { y: '2012 W7', a: 8, b: 40 }
            ]

        , day = [
                { y: '2012-12-25', a: 20, b: 50 },
                { y: '2012-12-26', a: 30,  b: 30 },
                { y: '2012-12-27', a: 100, b: 10 },
                { y: '2012-12-28', a: 10,  b: 15 },
                { y: '2012-12-29', a: 80,  b: 60 },
                { y: '2012-12-30', a: 20,  b: 65 },
                { y: '2012-12-31', a: 5, b: 95 }
            ]
        , data = {
            month: month,
            week: week,
            day: day
            }

        , line = new Morris.Line({
            element: 'line-chart',
            resize: true,
            data: data[type],
            xkey: 'y',
            ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
            labels: ['Price', 'Test'],
            lineColors: ['#3c8dbc', '#3c8dbc'],
            hideHover: 'auto'
        })
        ;
    });
   });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the onChange event on the select element, and then inside, you can call an API on the server side written with PHP. The data return from the server could then used to update the chart with the function setData().